# I want to display data from my database into a HTML div

Tags: php, html, database, output

I have my database set up, where all of my data is going to. Now, I want to display the data from my database into my website. How am I going to do this?

I want data that is in my database into the "informatie-en-hallo-text" .

```
<div class="informatie-en-hallo">
<div class="informatie-en-hallo-textblock">
    <img id="FrontpageBramF1" src="images/FrontpageFotoPF_transparant.png">
<div class="informatie-en-hallo-text">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque cursus viverra augue, vel molestie velit imperdiet eu. Nam euismod neque dictum nunc malesuada congue. Fusce gravida laoreet eleifend. Donec molestie aliquam orci et mattis. Etiam ut mi at velit congue tempus at in sem. Sed dignissim dui nisi, eu scelerisque nunc gravida eu. Etiam maximus, felis et hendrerit placerat, urna ipsum aliquam neque, quis maximus lacus ligula vel purus. Aliquam suscipit, orci in fermentum pulvinar, elit ante placerat nisi, sed feugiat odio odio vestibulum tellus. Aliquam dapibus vitae est eu semper. Nullam hendrerit sem vel dui cursus, vel semper quam laoreet. Proin lacinia ut massa nec fringilla. Fusce quis consequat ante.

    Ut mi ligula, consequat semper aliquam sit amet, facilisis sit amet elit. Sed sagittis diam sed sollicitudin vestibulum. Morbi nec bibendum erat. In dictum turpis vel metus consequat, quis finibus arcu tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti. Nam venenatis justo at sem volutpat aliquet. Morbi nunc nunc, fermentum vitae condimentum eu, laoreet ultricies tortor.

    Vivamus at diam quam. Nunc ullamcorper urna justo, eu maximus magna lacinia at. Curabitur sagittis vehicula erat. Etiam viverra ex orci, vel pulvinar eros pretium ut. Praesent eu semper orci. Vivamus vel lectus porttitor, consectetur risus at, venenatis justo. Donec consequat pellentesque maximus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla aliquet, leo ac congue ultrices, felis est cursus dolor, sollicitudin maximus augue purus id ex. Proin et lorem nec lorem congue ultricies a sit amet metus. Pellentesque vehicula, turpis quis condimentum mollis, lectus arcu imperdiet turpis, sit amet interdum lectus velit quis metus.

    Ut hendrerit eu quam a eleifend. Duis rhoncus sagittis sapien ac tempor. Duis euismod porttitor augue, eget laoreet sem lacinia et. Praesent a cursus dui. Maecenas ex massa, semper nec varius quis, iaculis ut massa. Aenean vulputate ipsum suscipit, tincidunt sem et, blandit nisl. Nulla in risus tellus. Morbi id purus purus. Sed imperdiet accumsan lectus nec bibendum. Curabitur dapibus velit vitae augue mattis venenatis. Duis sit amet feugiat mauris. Curabitur id diam nisl. Curabitur nibh tortor, consequat non pretium vitae, blandit a nibh. Donec rhoncus mattis quam, ut sollicitudin risus mattis vitae. Praesent non dapibus risus. Donec justo felis, pharetra volutpat venenatis et, condimentum vitae ipsum.

    Vivamus tristique urna nibh, sit amet vulputate urna volutpat id. Proin ut sapien magna. Donec posuere pharetra justo a condimentum. Quisque turpis orci, convallis in pulvinar id, hendrerit a enim. Vestibulum imperdiet enim eu est pharetra congue. Sed vel malesuada neque. Praesent at facilisis nibh. Donec odio arcu, pretium id diam non, accumsan consequat risus. Integer vulputate, ligula vel mollis pulvinar, ex ligula lobortis diam, et pretium diam erat sed purus. Donec lacinia lectus nec lorem facilisis, luctus convallis orci ullamcorper. Donec ipsum tellus, rhoncus id enim ac, elementum ullamcorper purus. Ut auctor tristique felis ut volutpat. In imperdiet libero in dui ultricies fermentum. Phasellus sit amet purus et mi facilisis sodales. Suspendisse potenti. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>


    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:** I'm sorry, the PHP code didn't load properly, but I will try it again.

*The value that has been submitted here:*

```
'<?php require VIEW_ROOT . '/templates/header.php';?>

 <h2>Nieuwe pagina toevoegen</h2>

 <form action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/admin/add.php" method="POST" 
  autocomplete="off">
 <label for="title">
    Paginatitel:
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
 </label>

<label for="label">
    Label:
    <input type="text" name="label" id="label">
</label>

<label for="slug">
    (Gewenste) slug:
    <input type="text" name="slug" id="slug">
</label>

<label for="body">
    Inhoud van de pagina:
    <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</label>

<input type="submit" value="Voeg pagina toe">
```

*will be processed here:*

```
<?php

require '../app/start.php';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
$label   = $_POST ['label'];
$title   = $_POST ['title'];
$slug    = $_POST ['slug'];
$body    = $_POST ['body'];

$insertPage = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO pages (label, title, slug, body, created)
    VALUES (:label, :title, :slug, :body, NOW())
");

$insertPage->execute([
    'label' => $label,
    'title' => $title,
    'slug'  => $slug,
    'body'  => $body,
]);

header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/list.php');
}

require VIEW_ROOT . '/admin/add.php';
```

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: You could have a REST service - the make a request to the database and the JavaScript on the page could load it into the div

Comment: Check mysqli_connect() to begin with.

Comment: I did it with PDO. Is this a big mistake? (I'm sorry, i'm just new with PHP, haha).

Answer (score 0):

In your html file open php tag and write your fetch query and loop through data where you need to display.
`

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
     $result = --fetch query--
  ?>

<?php
foreach($result as $value){
?>
<div>
  Name:<?php echo $value['name'];?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

`

This is a sample snippet.

Comment: What can I exactly write into `$result`?

Comment: There you write your select and fetch query.. Refer to this lesson https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp